# Automatic bibliography .bib file content generator

Tags: latex, tex, article, bibtex

I am looking for an online solution, where I enter a book, article, etc., then it searches and finds it, and provides me with the most complete reference that I can include in my .bib file for my article.

For example, let's say I enter the name of an article like:

`"Verification of sequential and concurrent programs"`,

and then it provides me with exactly what I will need to include in my .bib file as follows:

```
{
AptOlderog91,

  author = {K. R. Apt and E.-R. Olderog},

  title = {Verification of sequential and concurrent programs},

  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},

  year = 1991

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am sure there exists no single source that would provide this. A start would be [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do,

- Search on scholar.google.com, once you find the right artifact,
- look for "cite" link below, on selecting that, you get bib item in 3 default formats (MLA, APA and Chicago).
- In the pop up window, there is an option "import to bibtex" that returns a bib source which can be used in the bib file.

Beware, however, some of the bib entries are incomplete/incorrect. For that, there is no other option than going to the source (IEEE, ACM, Elsevier etc) and retrieving the bib.

Hope it helps!